# Why is Y = 22 on the first line print?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Hey was just wondering why the first iteration of `cout << x << " " << y;` = 3 22 ? Im confused as why its not 3, 2? can someone explain ?

```
int fun(int x, int y) {
    cout << x << " " << y;
    if (x == 0) {
        return y;
    }        

    return fun(x-1, x*y);
}

int main() {
    int result;
    result = fun(3,2);
}
```

RESULT: 3 22 61 120 12

Comment: It is `3 2`, you just print the next output without any sort of spacing. `cout << x << " " << y;` -> `cout << x << " " << y << "\n";`

Comment: Your `fun` is recursive. "3 2" is what the first level call outputs, but that is not the end of the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "3 22" it's "3 2" followed by "2 6" from the next call to `f()`. Add a newline to separate the lines in the recursive calls.

```
std::cout << x << " " << y << '\n';
```

and you'll see the output

```
3 2
2 6
1 12
0 12
```

[live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FKixup8GtSlLeBAF)